# Breakout collision with block laterally

Tags: c#

I am creating a breakout game in c#.
Everything is working fine excepting one feature

My blocks are destroyed after the second hit ,but if the ball hits the side (left or right) of the block , the block is destroyed instantly..

Example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73iaDUxo4AE)

What's the feature needed to avoid this problem ? 
Thanks in advance ! 
Here is the code where the "action"  is happening :

```
foreach(Control x in this.Controls)
        {

            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "block")
            {
                if (ball1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                {        
                    x.Tag = "Hit";
                    bally = -bally;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "Hit")
                    if (ball1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                       bally = -bally;
                        this.Controls.Remove(x);
                        if(score<=5)
                            speed = speed + 1;
                    }
            }
        }
```

x - my blocks

```
Point pt = ball1.Location;
if (pt.X < 0 || pt.X > ClientRectangle.Width - ball1.Width)
            ballx = -ballx;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see where your code for bouncing the ball in the x direction is? I only see `bally = -bally;` where is the reflection for the ball's x movement on a side-block collision (presumably `ballx = -ballx;`)?

Comment: I edited my post. That's my only reflection on a side collision. Should I add one more case ? What should the condition be ?

Comment: That code appears only to account for edge collision with the frame of the window, not with collision with the side of any block?

Comment: And how do I check the collision with a side of a block ?

Comment: Given that you're not checking which side of the block you're colliding with, I think your question is now a duplicate of this one: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22609/breakout-collision-detecting-the-side-of-collision (although that's in Java, it makes no material difference)